# How to pass parameters to Symfony Form CollectionType

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, symfony-forms

***Intro***

I have a simple form.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add($builder
        ->create('oneItemToSubmit', TextType::class), array(
            'entry_type' => TextType::class,
    ));
}
```

When i submit it with an `array (["oneItem" => '1'])`, i get the desired output i.e. My data_class object gets hydrated correctly

***Problem***

I want to submit an array of listOfItems `array (["listOfItems" => ['1', '2', '3'])` and get an array of my hydrated data_class Objects hydrated correctly

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add($builder
        ->create('listOfItems', CollectionType::class), array(
            'entry_type' => TextType::class,
    ));
}
```

***Question***

How do I achieve this with the `CollectionType::class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
 $options){
     $builder->add($builder
              ->create('oneItemToSubmit', TextType::class), array(
                        'class' => CollectionType::class,
                        'entry_type' => TextType::class,
               ));
          }
```

Comment: Simply put, you are amazing haha. I'll go read up on the documentation for the create method again. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('listOfItems', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type'   => TextType::class,
        'entry_options'  => array(
        'attr'      => array('class' => 'list-box')
            ),
        ));
   }
```

Comment: I'll look at this solution too
,
Cheers!